# Parse IF condition using Regular Expression

Tags: regex

I need to create the RE meets the following IF condition

```
 string InputValue=" If (X.Value==” X”) then   X.Value = “X”;
    Elseif (X.Value==” X”) then X.Value = “X”;
    Elseif (X.Value==” Y ") then X.Value = “Y”;
    Elseif (X.Value== ” Z ")  then X.Value = “Z”;
    Else X.Value = “M”;";
```

as you know its only 1 if and 0 or many ElseIF and 0 or 1 Else and also i want to consider space and Enter
I try to use the following RE but its failed

```
    string pattern="If\([a-z]*\.Value==""[a-z]*""\) Then [a-z]*\.Value=""[a-z]*""\;
(ElseIf\([a-z]*\.Value==""[a-z]*""\) Then [a-z]*\.Value=""[a-z]*""\;)*
(Else [a-z]*\.Value=""[a-z]*""\;)?";

bool result = Regex.IsMatch(InputValue, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

All ideas are welcomed

Comment: @minitech : its used in C# application but if condition its my cutom condition that I need to validate . I also update the post

Comment: Please check: a) `if` is caps in the example but small letters in the regex. b) Space is missing between `if` and `(`. c) additional spaces after `then` and before `then` in the example but not in the regex. d) capital `X` in your example but only lowercase matches in your regex.

Comment: it's a trick question -- the if()..elseif..else block you've supplied sets `X.Value="X"` in every possible condition, since all the if and elseif conditions set it to "X", and so does the final else.

Comment: @Howard : I fixed what you said but man I think its another issue in repeating Elseif statment and Else

Comment: @Spudley : I updated it to be clear but man X , y or z its any stament .its only symbol

Answer (score 0):

As in http://ideone.com/onS2e:

```
string condition  = @"[_a-z]\w* \.VALUE \s* == \s* "" [^""]* """;
string assignment = @"[_a-z]\w* \.VALUE \s* =  \s* "" [^""]* "" \s* ;";
string pattern    = string.Format(
    @"\b     IF \s* \( \s* {0} \s* \) \s* THEN \s+ {1} \s*
    ( \b ELSEIF \s* \( \s* {0} \s* \) \s* THEN \s+ {1} \s* )*  # repeat ELSEIF any number of times
    ( \b ELSE                                  \s+ {1}     )?  # at most one ELSE",
    condition, assignment);

Regex myRegex = new Regex( pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace |
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline );
```

Updated:

As in http://ideone.com/1coOp:

```
string pattern    = string.Format(
    @"^ \s*    IF \s* \( \s* {0} \s* \) \s* THEN \s+ {1} \s*
      ( \b ELSEIF \s* \( \s* {0} \s* \) \s* THEN \s+ {1} \s* )*  # repeat ELSEIF any number of times
      ( \b ELSE                                  \s+ {1}     )?  # at most one ELSE
        \s* $",
    condition, assignment);
```

Comment: thanks mousio for your support but when I try to test it it failed if you add another Else it show success however you set it 0 or 1 else

Comment: I think you need to enclose the pattern between `^\s*` (front) and `\s*$` (end), but be sure not to put the latter in the comment parts (`#` and the text after it). Have you tried the ideone link? The input I used there only differs in the quotes, compared to your posted input, as I assumed all `“` and `”` were meant to be `"`. The ideone output is based on the regex's `Matches` (i.e. substrings that match the pattern) instead of `IsMatch()`, that probably explains our different results?

Comment: when I write if iffff it also pass success

Comment: Then please clarify what should and what should not match, give examples, details or add some context to your question… If you understand what the pattern expresses, it would make things so much easier. So head on over to http://regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html to read about it, and then play with it in your code or on http://nregex.com or on http://regexhero.net/tester.